# In C++11 std::atomic, what is the memory_order used for operators like ++, -- and +=?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, atomic

It seems that unlike the member functions, you don't get to specify which memory_order to use, so there's probably some 'default' that ends up being used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (§29.7/35), the **effect** of calling `operator++` of an atomic type `A` with non-atomic base type `C`, i.e. one of these:

```
C A::operator++() volatile noexcept;
C A::operator++() noexcept;
```

**is the same as that of calling the member function `fetch_add(1)`**, and according to §29.5 (initial declarations), the latter is declared with a default argument:

```
C fetch_add(C, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile noexcept;
C fetch_add(C, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst) noexcept;
```

for integral types `C`, and:

```
C* fetch_add(ptrdiff_t, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile noexcept;
C* fetch_add(ptrdiff_t, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst) noexcept;
```

for address types. **In other words, the default memory order used by `operator++` is `memory_order_seq_cst`.**

The Standard does not make any such statement about `operator+=`, although it seems natural to assume that what is true of `operator++` is also true of `operator+=` in this context.

Also note there is the general rule for functions of atomic types defined by the Standard:

> (§29.6.5/2) [...] the free functions not ending in `_explicit` have the semantics of their corresponding `_explicit` with memory_order arguments of `memory_order_seq_cst`.

Answer (score 7):

Default is "sequentially consistent".